# Can you stream podcasts from the server to the iPad or iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, osx-server, podcasts, mobile-safari

So we are having a problem right now regarding the Lion Server and streaming podcast.
We already did the steps on technical note [TS4126](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4126) and now we can play the podcasts made from podcast producer on the server's webpage on Safari on MAC OS X. The problem we're having right now is that we can't play it on Safari on iPad, and on iPhone (via a mobile-format webpage version) the Podcast page isn't even available.

My question is that is it possible to stream podcasts from the Lion server to the iPhone or iPad, or is it even possible to view the podcasts via a different method?

We specifically asks for Lion because we don't have prior experience with the previous servers, but anything that can help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - It's as simple as posting a sound file to the web server and iOS devices can stream it easily. It's more about setting the video settings for streaming hinting than a setting on server.

This is a supported function of Lion server since it provides the tools you need to create and self-publish podcasts.

- http://www.apple.com/macosx/server/features/all.html#podcasting

As to the https errors, make sure your iPads have a profile that trust the certificate you have loaded into the web server and don't warn you when browsing the general web server using https.

Troubleshooting server is challenging in a Q&A format, but depending on your definition of "streaming" this works once Lion server and the client trust each other for normal podcast downloading.

You might try uploading an episode to the wiki and see if you can rule out the problem for your setup.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if this information helps. How about the iPhone? 
I think that troubleshooting server is really challenging in a Q&A format. I'll try posting this question on a forum.